# listview builder has low fps(18.7 in android simulation) when scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a fixed `controller.groupedList` in the form of `Map<dynamic,List<Event>>` and I put this into a List.builder as followings, try to get a list:

```
ListView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: scrollController,
      key: _animatedKey,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: controller.yearOld,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        var keys = controller.groupedList.keys.toList();
        var thisYearList = controller.groupedList[keys[index]];
        print('thisYearList= $thisYearList'); //it will be triggered by each pixel scrolling

        return TimelineItemWidget(
            controller: controller,
            index: index,
            thisYearList: thisYearList);
      },
    );
```

Now my question, it seems each pixel I scrolled,  the print method is triggered, so I guess from each pixel I scroll the screen, ListView tried to run my method which transform `Map<Int,List<Event>>` to `thisYearList`, and therefore it leads to a low fps.

In the dart coding world, is there a better way to solve this issue? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not the dart coding world.  The flutter coding world.  You have ignored that build() might fire 60 times per second constantly, which means that build() should be quick and idempotent, and not perform synchronous I/O.

Comment: You need to understand how Listview.builder works, it doesn't build all items at once, instead only those items which fit into the current screen, as you scroll downward it starts to build new items,

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, for instance a widget from Listview.builder has height 100 px, so each px I scroll downward inside this 100 px height, the build() will fire? Could you plz let me know how to avoid this situaion, I mean if I am scrolling inside this same Widget, listview.builder should avoid to build same stuff, thanks